# Why different values of matrix inside and outside class method?

Tags: python, class

When I try to print the values of my global variable *matrix* from inside and outside class, I got different values. After I set `matrix = self.A` , I made some changes in `self.A`. But can it cause problem?  Thanks in advance.

```
def function:
    obj=X()
    print matrix

class X():
    def __init__():
        self.A = numpy.zeros([len(self.words), self.dcount])
        for i, k in enumerate(self.words):
            for d in self.wdict[k]:
                self.A[i,d] += 1 
        global matrix
        matrix = self.A
        print matrix
        # make some changes in self.A
        .
        .
        .  

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    function()
```

Comment: Side note: why are using `global`? I've never seen a good use of `global`.

Comment: You mention making changes to `self.A` after `matrix` has been set to it. `matrix` will only take the value of `self.A` when you assign it. Further changes to `self.A` will not automatically update `matrix`. On a separate note, it is not usually a good idea to use global variables (keep global for constants or singletons). However, declaring `global matrix` like you have done should allow the method to update `matrix` - it may be getting changed somewhere.

Comment: "Further changes to self.A will not automatically update matrix." It will! Because `self.A` is a mutable type, `matrix` and `self.A` point to the same object, so both will be changed when you change one of them.

Comment: @eqperes Yes it is changing. How can I get the previous value of A matrix?

Comment: @eqperes Yep you’re right. Sorry - I misread the situation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `self.A` is a numpy array, which is mutable. This means that when you change `self.A`, `matrix` will be changed as well.

If you want `matrix` to be equal to the value of `self.A` at the moment of the assignment, and for it not to be changed after, you need to make a [copy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html):

```
matrix = numpy.copy(self.A)
```